# Extract Unique Value by Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to Get the Unique Teams by User

I need to grab and display what teams a user was and is on.

```
Team Name | Email Address
BTA       | user1@domain.com
YRE       | user2@domain.com
BTR       | user3@domain.com
TAS       | user1@domain.com
GGS       | user2@domain.com
TAS       | user4@domain.com
GGS       | user3@domain.com
```

When searching for "user1@domain.com" it would display

```
Team Name
BTA
TAS
```

it cant use shift+ctrl+enter

I'm able to do it with teams and drag down using the below code, but how do I add criteria to it?

```
IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Team Name],MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($F$1:F1,Table1[Team Name]),),0)),"")
```

and drag down works

F1 is above the selected cell.

Designed outcome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNPCv.png

Comment: What other criteria are you talking about?

Comment: Only by Email for now, I need to bring back unique Teams for that users email, other criteria would be date, between 2 dates (start, finish)

Comment: Why you cannot use shift+ctrl+enter?

Comment: Can it be done with shift+ctrl+enter? main reason was, I may in future need to use it for excel 365 online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

[image]

I included an offline array formula in `E2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$8,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$8=$D$2,ROW($B$2:$B$8),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

and an online version in `F2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$8,AGGREGATE(15,3,($B$2:$B$8=$D$2)*(ROW($B$2:$B$8)),COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,"<>"&$D$2)+ROW(A1))),"")
```

With new criteria in new columns, you can extend the logic of `($B$2:$B$8=$D$2)*(ROW($B$2:$B$8)` and replace `COUNTIF` with `COUNTIFS`

Comment: That works great for pulling the data, with that, how can I only display Unique if the email address is then assigned in again there it is duplicated

Comment: @kire38, I'm not understanding what you say. If this is new relevant information, please add in your original question for others to reference to.

Comment: I've managed to get Unique Teams with this code: `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($H$1:H1,$A$2:$A$11),),0)),"")` but how do I combine your code with the unique code?