# Obtain Unique Values from Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need to Obtain the Unique Values from Teams with the criteria being the users email.

from my previous question [Extract Unique Value by Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57038066/extract-unique-value-by-criteria) we managed to extract the teams from that match the email.

but I'm needing the teams that are matched to be unique.

I managed to get unique teams with this code
    `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($H$1:H1,$A$2:$A$11),),0)),"")`

how do I combine
    `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$8,AGGREGATE(15,3,($B$2:$B$8=$D$2)*(ROW($B$2:$B$8)),COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8,"<>"&$D$2)+ROW(A1))),"")`

with
    `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($H$1:H1,$A$2:$A$11),),0)),"")`

The end result should be only 1 of each team

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid without the use of arrays you will have to include a helper column, which on it's own might be good enough, it's just that values won't be added underneath eachother:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=IF(B2=$D$2,IF(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,A2)=1,"",A2),"")
```

Formula in `F2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:$E$11,AGGREGATE(15,3,($E$2:$E$11<>"")*ROW($E$2:$E$11),COUNTIF($E$2:$E$11,"")+ROW(A1))),"")
```